# Add a condition according a hook parameter using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next hook in my react js application:

```js
const {
  data,
  loading
} = fetchData(info)({
  variables: {
    id: myId,
  },
  fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
});

//
const fetchData = (info) => {
  if (a > 1) {
    return useGetCars;
  }
  return useGetColors;
};
```

The issue appear in the first render when the `myId` is empty, but it is **required**. Due this fact i get an error from the server.
**Question**: How to create a condition for the hook above to be able to run it only when the `myId` is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

Use the effect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (myId) {
   fetchData() // after this, you can set the required states.
  }
}, [myId])
```

Comment: if i do this `fetchData()` requires the `info` param, plus how  apply destructurization inside useEffect and access destructurized data from useEffect?

Comment: could you help with this?

Comment: You can do in same manner. And set the state from the result of fetchData.

Comment: could you show please, because i am confused. Thanks